# document.querySelector returning null for html inject with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Revising a previous question as I think I have discovered what the specific issue is. I am injecting some html via javascript with the following code:

```
    var clickFn = function(e) {
    console.log("click registered");
    e.preventDefault();
    //console.log("id is" + " " + this.id);
    dropdown.classList.remove("open");
    btn.innerHTML = this.text;
    var activeLink = document.querySelector(".option .active");

    searchBoxes = parseInt(this.id);
    inputFieldHTML = [];

    for(i=0; i<searchBoxes; i++) {
      //j = i +1;
      inputFieldHTML.push('<input placeholder="Search" class="Box" type="text" id="gearInput' + i + '"' + "/>" + '<div class="ccontainer"><div class="cdropdown"> <button class="ctitle"><span class="cselectorText">dynamically injeced menu</span></button> <ul class="cdropdown-options"> <li class="coption"><a href="#">option 1</a></li> <li class="coption"><a href="#">option2</a></li></ul></div></div></div>' );
    }


    document.getElementById("inputBoxes").innerHTML = inputFieldHTML.join("");

    if (activeLink) {
      activeLink.classList.remove("active");
    }

    this.classList.add("active");
};

for (var i = 0; i < optionLinks.length; i++) {
   optionLinks[i].addEventListener("mousedown", clickFn, false);
}
```

After those elements are created I need to create the following objects:

```
var coptionLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".coption a");
var cbtn = document.querySelector(".ctitle");
var cdropdown = document.querySelector(".cdropdown-options");
```

These are all returning null as they are being set before being created by the previous loop. How can I ensure I set these after the for loop has completed.

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Use ::ng-deep or put your code in global styles.css file

Answer (score 0):

[I don't get null values.](https://jsfiddle.net/f47oeL4h/) In how far does this example differ from yours?

**HTML**

```
<div id="inputBoxes"></div>
```

**JS**

```
(function() {

var inputFieldHTML = [];

for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
      //j = i +1;
      inputFieldHTML.push('<input placeholder="Search" class="Box" type="text" id="gearInput' + i + '"' + "/>" + '<div class="cdropdown"> <button class="ctitle"><span class="cselectorText">Dynamically Generated Selector</span></button> <ul class="cdropdown-options"> <li class="coption"><a <href="#">option 1</a></li> <li class="coption"><a <href="#">option 2</a></li></ul></div</div>')
   }
 document.getElementById("inputBoxes").innerHTML = inputFieldHTML.join("");

var coptionLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".coption a");
var cbtn = document.querySelector(".ctitle");
var cdropdown = document.querySelector(".cdropdown-options");

console.log(coptionLinks);
console.log(cbtn);
console.log(cdropdown);

})()
```

Comment: updated original post with the entire function surrounding the for loop. That function controls the behavior of a menu that creates inputs fields and another menu for each field.